# Rails & Ajax: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/103")

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm getting the following error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/103")

rake routes:

```
                  PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                  PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
```

My form:

```
 <%= form_for current_user, id: 'photoinfo', html: { multipart: true }, :remote => true do |f| %>

    <%= f.file_field :avatar, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg, image/jpg', id: 'uploadAvatar' %>

    <%= f.submit 'Submit Photo', id: 'submitPhoto' %>

 <% end %>
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $('.edit_user').attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: result,
        dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
    }).success(function(json){
        console.log("success", json);
    });
    return false; // prevents normal behaviour
```

Where am I going wrong? Why is it saying no route matches?

Comment: You are doing a "POST" request, but the available routes are "PUT" and "PATCH"

Comment: You don't appear to have a POST route, only a PUT (and the synonymous PATCH) route.  Either make another route for POST in `routes.rb` or adjust your form or AJAX to use PUT method.

Comment: Oh, damn. Silly mistake, thanks